# Vim: Move all comments the top of the file

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I have a Perl file, and I want to move all the comments on top.

Perl comments begin with a #.

I tried something like:

```
:g:^\s*#.*:m
```

Comment: Comments tend to lose meaning (sometimes lose _all_ meaning) when moved away from the lines of code they refer to. So I'm curious why you want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the address to send the line to which is 0.

```
:g:^\s*#:m0
```

For more help see `:h :m`

Answer (score 0):

Think i found the issue, I've ommited the line number

```
:g:^\s*#.*:m0
```